# Tags and Category list pages for blog not loading on Jekyll Site

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-theme

really in a predicament and this may be a specific question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I've been a long time SO lurker and just made an account to ask this question and SO won't let me post with so many links so bare with me please)

So I have been working on my blog for quite awhile, it is live [here](https://colefeely6.github.io/), the GitHub is [here](https://github.com/ColeFeely6/ColeFeely6.github.io) and it is based off the Jekyll template [al-folio](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio). My issue is that on the original site, you can see blog posts with this url: https://alshedivat.github.io/al-folio/blog/ and you can click on the tags or categories to get a list of all the posts under those like /https://alshedivat.github.io/al-folio/blog/tag/formatting/ or site url /al-folio/blog/category/sample-posts/>.

My version should not have anything differently, I still have all the default blog posts such as [this one](https://colefeely6.github.io/blog/2015/code/) and [my own](https://colefeely6.github.io/blog/2023/wisconsin-method/) which also is hosted on the website (so the issue isn't with making new blogs. it's just not loading the page that lists all the blog posts under that category).

My problem is that I do not know why something like /blog/tag/formatting is a broken link on my site but it works on the original. Same issue for categories.

I tried to start an issue on the  the template's GitHub and no one has replied there. The issue seems to be that the _layout/archive-tag.html, _layout/archive-category.html and _layout/archive-year.html are not working but whichever file that loads the actual blog post is working, either _post or _page. So the issue must be with whatever loads these because the code is exactly the same as the original site. I may be completely wrong with this assumption.

Comment: My issue that I opened can be found [here](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/issues/1195)

Comment: Issue may be with the _blog/index.html not executing properly